# tess-two Android Studio app has stopped at data path

Tags: java, android, tesseract, tess-two

I am starting off simple with `tess-two` in `Android Studio` (after I managed to import the pre-compiled version of `Tesseract` into my project!) so I keep adding single lines and moving forward...

In `strings.xml` under `values` under `res`, I have defined the following data path:

```
<string name="data_path">/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.01/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata</string>
```

However, the `baseApi.init` line crashes my `Empty Activity` app that would normally build to device and say `Hello World`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Attempt to initialize the API.
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();

        // Initialize the language training file path.
        // See 'strings.xml' under 'values' under 'res'.
        String DATA_PATH = getString(R.string.data_path);

        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, "eng"); // <-- TessAndroid has stopped!
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to note is that `data_path` needs to be a path that exists on your Android device.

Comment: @rmtheis Thanks for the tip. I thought similar to a Unity3D project that copies this file to device via `StreamingAssets`, AndroidStudio would do the same when building to device... How do I do that? Do I need to do so manually using something like `SmartSwitch`? Or somehow in my AndroidStudio code?

Comment: You can use AssetManager to copy the files to the device storage. See my android-ocr project for an [example](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr/blob/c7a8bfc7e0f38279f147aa68826c93cfac8fe579/OCRTest/src/main/java/edu/sfsu/cs/orange/ocr/OcrInitAsyncTask.java#L601) of this.

Comment: @rmtheis Thanks, but in your example, there is no mention of `AssetManager`... Also, there is no `asset` folder in my `AndroidStudio` app. Is this something I should create manually?

Comment: [`getAssets()`](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr/blob/c7a8bfc7e0f38279f147aa68826c93cfac8fe579/OCRTest/src/main/java/edu/sfsu/cs/orange/ocr/OcrInitAsyncTask.java#L619) returns an `AssetManager`; Yes